# Development Site - This site can’t provide a secure connection

Tags: security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have moved a client website across to a subdomain of my companies website for development.

The client website has a working SSL certificate. Successfully redirects to https:// - everything works like a charm.

I have straight copied the code to the development folder and gone to load the page and receive the error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
Site sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I go to the security tab within Chrome and can see the certificate is valid and trusted. The resources are all served securely. However I am unable to access the site as 'This page is not secure.':

```
This page is not secure.
Certificate - valid and trusted
The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by unknown name.
Resources - all served securely
All resources on this page are served securely.
```

As this is only a development site I am happy for it to not be secure - so long as the live site stays secure and my clients are able to view the development site.